# Ubuntu 14.4 running slow

Tags: performance, ubuntu-14.04, lag

I just bought the new Dell XPS 13 Developer edition which came preinstalled with ubuntu 14.04.

After the initial boot it seemed a bit slow, but then it updated and worked fine, then later the same day seemed to slow down again.

Even running programs like eclipse it seems very laggy on, which is odd. As the specifications should be fine;
16gb Ram
i7-6560U cpu
64-bit
500gb ssd.

I'm not sure what to post to help, so any suggestions would be great.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Check what is using much system load using the command `top`.

You can also use `htop` which is easier to read.

For that install it using the following command:

`sudo apt-get install htop`

Have you tried reinstalling Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS on your computer?

In future, please use the [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) forums for such questions.

Comment: thank you for the advice, and I will post this on the ubuntu forum (didn't realise there was one). I ran htop, but nothing out of the ordinary, the the process using the most was just chromium at around 5-7% cpu usage, and not a lot of memory taken up either.

Comment: Then the problem could be a system error or similar, please try reinstalling ubuntu and report if the problem persists. Also try other OSes, if they do the same, then it could be a hardware-side defect.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue in my lenovo thinkpad with i7 and 16GB. pycharm and android studio was exteremely slow and it was almost not usable for any development. Even it took a while for the terminal to start.

Finally I found a solution for my issue. I needed to disable "speed step" feature in BIOS.

Please read the following blog for more information

http://www.williambharding.com/blog/technology/fixed-my-i7-intel-dell-laptop-is-ridiculously-slow/